# AspNetBoilerPlate AutoMapper Exception When mapping a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

Im using AspNetBoilerPlate Core and im having a problem mapping a list of items to a viewmodel

i have this DTO in the application layer

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(LeadMeta.LeadMeta))]
public class LeadMetaDto : EntityDto
{
    public int LeadId { get; set; }
    public int? TenantId { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyKey { get; set; }
}
```

i want to map it to an identical viewmodel in the mvc layer, so i do the following from my controller

```
var lead = await _leadAppService.Get(Id);
enquiry.LeadMeta = new List<DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel>(lead.LeadMeta);
```

an this is the DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(LeadMetaDto))]
public class DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel: LeadMetaDto
{
    public DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel(LeadMetaDto output)
    {
        output.MapTo(this);
    }
}
```

However my attempts are producing the following error :

> INFO  2019-09-05 19:16:47,551 [9    ]
>   ore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker - Executing action method
>   PowerITCRM.Web.Controllers.LeadController.Dashboard
>   (PowerITCRM.Web.Mvc) with arguments (13005) - Validation state: Valid
>   ERROR 2019-09-05 19:16:48,427 [6    ]
>   Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: IEnumerable`1 -> List`1
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[PowerITCRM.Features.Lead.LeadMetaDto,
>   PowerITCRM.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] ->
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PowerITCRM.Web.Models.Lead.DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel,
>   PowerITCRM.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error
>   mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: IEnumerable`1 -> List`1
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[PowerITCRM.Features.Lead.LeadMetaDto,
>   PowerITCRM.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] ->
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PowerITCRM.Web.Models.Lead.DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel,
>   PowerITCRM.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] ---> System.ArgumentException:
>   PowerITCRM.Web.Models.Lead.DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel needs to have
>   a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. Parameter name: type 
>   at lambda_method(Closure , IEnumerable`1 , List`1 , ResolutionContext
>   )    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , IEnumerable`1 , List`1 , ResolutionContext )
>   at
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource
>   source, TDestination destination) in
>   C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 271    at
>   PowerITCRM.Web.Controllers.LeadController.Dashboard(Int32 Id) in
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\PowerITCRM\src\PowerITCRM.Web.Mvc\Controllers\LeadController.cs:line
>   126    at lambda_method(Closure , Object )    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()
>   INFO  2019-09-05 19:16:48,434 [6    ]
>   ore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker - Executed action
>   PowerITCRM.Web.Controllers.LeadController.Dashboard
>   (PowerITCRM.Web.Mvc) in 898.9158ms ERROR 2019-09-05 19:16:48,618 [6
>   ] nostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware - An unhandled exception
>   has occurred while executing the request.
>   AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: IEnumerable`1 -> List`1
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[PowerITCRM.Features.Lead.LeadMetaDto,
>   PowerITCRM.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] ->
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PowerITCRM.Web.Models.Lead.DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel,
>   PowerITCRM.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] ---> System.ArgumentException:
>   PowerITCRM.Web.Models.Lead.DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel needs to have
>   a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. Parameter name: type 
>   at lambda_method(Closure , IEnumerable`1 , List`1 , ResolutionContext
>   )    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , IEnumerable`1 , List`1 , ResolutionContext )
>   at
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource
>   source, TDestination destination) in
>   C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 271    at
>   PowerITCRM.Web.Controllers.LeadController.Dashboard(Int32 Id) in
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\PowerITCRM\src\PowerITCRM.Web.Mvc\Controllers\LeadController.cs:line
>   126    at lambda_method(Closure , Object )    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   PowerITCRM.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtTokenMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\PowerITCRM\src\PowerITCRM.Web.Core\Authentication\JwtBearer\JwtTokenMiddleware.cs:line
>   22
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context) DEBUG 2019-09-05 19:16:48,713 [9    ]
>   Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs.AbpCommonHub - A client is disconnected:
>   fpR1HzE9UYrEMvP_yNR28w INFO  2019-09-05 19:16:48,758 [13   ]
>   soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request finished in
>   4111.2398ms 101  INFO  2019-09-05 19:16:48,854 [6    ] soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request finished in
>   1333.083ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: PowerITCRM.Web.Models.Lead.DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. It clearly doesn't.

Comment: Could you provide a working  example, I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look likes this :

```
var lead = await _leadAppService.Get(Id);
enquiry.LeadMeta = new List<DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel>
{
    new DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel(lead.LeadMeta)
    //or lead.LeadMeta.MapTo<DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel>();
};
```

This part of your code causes the exception:

```
enquiry.LeadMeta = new List<DashboardEnquiryMetaViewModel>(lead.LeadMeta);
```

You are passing the object to the constructor of the list, not the ViewModel!

Comment: I was unable to get this to work. The line above the comment produced the same error, the commented line produced unmapped properties for all the fields

Comment: the next assumption is to rename your namespace. I think [AutoMapFrom(typeof(**LeadMeta.LeadMeta**))] causes the issue. Could you please try renaming the namespace of LeadMeta ?!